# Javascript fired from ASP.net codebehind runs in Chrome but not in IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a strange issue with a small bit of code, which runs fine in Chrome but wont fire in IE9.

I have a sub:

```
Private Sub MessageBox(ByVal msg As String)
        Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.alert('" + msg + "'); window.history.back(1); return false;</script>")
End Sub
```

Which is called in the Page_Load event if the page is marked as unpublished in the database.

This works fine in Chrome, but not at all in IE (and yes i have checked JS is enabled!)

Comment: Did you verify console in developer tools (F12)? It has any error?

Answer (score 0):

Or you may write the JavaScript code in a new line or as a new JavaScript function:

```
Private Sub MessageBox(ByVal msg As String)
    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>")
    Response.Write("window.alert('" + msg + "'); window.history.back(1); return false;")
    Response.Write("</script>")
End Sub
```

So that the JavaScript code is written in a new line separate from the markup.

Or you may try to use `RegisterStartupScript` if you're using `ASP.Net`

> Please use this answer as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.